# Cosmology tripped up by eV-scale physics?

Tags: cosmology

There has been an emerging [Hubble tension](https://www.particlebites.com/?tag=hubble-tension) in which a cosmic-microwave background based estimation produces a value of about 67 (km/s)/Mpc while distance-ladder based methods cluster around 73. This difference isn't huge but it has reached a 5-sigma significance.

Many exotic particles, modified physics, and other phenomena that go well beyond our experimental capabilities have been proposed to solve it. However, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05874) proposes that our models of [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)) may need to be adjusted and doing so would ease the tension. In essence, it claims we need to better account for the many-body dynamics at the eV scale in the  cooling plasma.

Can the paper's claims be refuted or could they have solved one of cosmology's biggest problems? If the scattering lengths that set the scale of fluctuations are far enough from our understanding it may change the results.

Comment: maybe you should also try https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: People publish paper that *may* (or may not) "solve" major problems every day of the week.  Alas, this is very rarely the case.  Your question is probably opinion based and hence off-topic, as only time (and further theory and experiment and peer review) will tell if there is anything to this paper.